Oracle SQL Query to Retrieve Values in a "Pyramidal" Fetch?
Please note I don't know if this "pyramidal format" has an official name: I might be using the incorrect convention.
I need to create an SQL script that is able to fetch from this table.

(Text Format)
MCU|MPF|AN8|PRODF|PRODM|LITM|VAL
112| |0| | | |Value006
112|431|0| | | |Value005
112|431|9999| | | |Value004
112|431|9999|VAL001| | |Value003
112|431|9999|VAL001|VAL002| |Value002
112|431|9999|VAL001|VAL002|TEST-MR-001|Value001

The idea is to prioritize the record with the most information when doing a JOIN. Meaning it should be:

PCLITM
If PCLITM is blank-null, then PCPRODM.
If PCPRODM is blank-null, then PCPRODF.

... & so on.
I need to pull result value VAL from the configuration table, but there needs to always be a result, meaning non-exact matches are acceptable.
Transactions' Table is...

(Text Format: Transaction Table)
DOCO|MCU|MPF|AN8|PRODF|PRODM|LITM|FETCH_RESULT
10001|112|431|9999|VAL001|VAL002|TEST-MR-001
10002|112|431|9999|VAL001|VAL003|TEST-MR-098
10003|112|431|9999|VAL014|VAL055|TEST-MR-005
10004|112|431|9999|VAL012|VAL050|TEST-MR-023
10005|112|345|1293|STK001|STK067|TEST-MR-004

Finally, here is the JOIN: the idea is to JOIN the transaction table to its respective value in the pyramid configuration table. This is the desired output:

(Text Format: Desired Output):
DOCO|MCU|MPF|AN8|PRODF|PRODM|LITM|FETCH_RESULT
10001|112|431|9999|VAL001|VAL002|TEST-MR-001|Value001
10002|112|431|9999|VAL001|VAL003|TEST-MR-098|Value003
10003|112|431|9999|VAL014|VAL055|TEST-MR-005|Value004
10004|112|431|9999|VAL012|VAL050|TEST-MR-023|Value004
10005|112|345|1293|STK001|STK067|TEST-MR-004|Value006

As an example take DOCO 10003: the best match is the combination of MCU 112, MPF 431 & AN8 9999, while PRODF, PRODM & LITM are blank.
What I'm trying to avoid is doing multiple JOINs to achieve the result, so I wanted to reach out to see if you know of a more efficient option.
This is a sample SQL to simulate both tables.
WITH PYRAMID_TABLE AS (
    SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL002' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-001' LITM, 'Value001' VAL FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL002' PRODM, ' ' LITM, 'Value002' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, ' ' PRODM, ' ' LITM, 'Value003' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, ' ' PRODF, ' ' PRODM, ' ' LITM, 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 0 AN8, ' ' PRODF, ' ' PRODM, ' ' LITM, 'Value005' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '112' MCU, ' ' MPF, 0 AN8, ' ' PRODF, ' ' PRODM, ' ' LITM, 'Value006' FROM DUAL),
     TRANSACTION_TABLE AS (
        SELECT 10001 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL002' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-001' LITM, 'Value001' Fetch_result FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 10002 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL003' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-098' LITM, 'Value003' FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 10003 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL014' PRODF, 'VAL055' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-005' LITM, 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 10004 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL012' PRODF, 'VAL050' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-023' LITM, 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION
        SELECT 10005 DOCO, '112' MCU, '345' MPF, 1293 AN8, 'STK001' PRODF, 'STK067' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-004' LITM, 'Value006' FROM DUAL)
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE;
--SELECT * FROM PYRAMID_TABLE;

Edit 1: Just clarifying: the aim is not to ORDER this pyramid so it is shown as in the image, but rather to be able to do a fetch between two tables, the transaction table being primary & fetching the correct result from the pyramid configuration table, but without skipping if an exact value doesn't exist. An apologize for any misunderstanding.

Please post formatted text rather than images, and include the output you are trying to get for the sample data. It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do or why.

From Oracle 12, you can use a LATERAL join combined with FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY:
SELECT *
FROM   transaction_table t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT val
         FROM   pyramid_table p
         WHERE  t.mcu = p.mcu
         AND    (  (t.mpf = p.mpf AND t.an8 = p.an8 AND t.prodf = p.prodf AND t.prodm = p.prodm AND t.litm = p.litm)
                OR (t.mpf = p.mpf AND t.an8 = p.an8 AND t.prodf = p.prodf AND t.prodm = p.prodm AND p.litm IS NULL)
                OR (t.mpf = p.mpf AND t.an8 = p.an8 AND t.prodf = p.prodf AND p.prodm IS NULL AND p.litm IS NULL)
                OR (t.mpf = p.mpf AND t.an8 = p.an8 AND p.prodf IS NULL AND p.prodm IS NULL AND p.litm IS NULL)
                OR (t.mpf = p.mpf AND p.an8 = 0 AND p.prodf IS NULL AND p.prodm IS NULL AND p.litm IS NULL)
                OR (p.mpf IS NULL AND p.an8 = 0 AND p.prodf IS NULL AND p.prodm IS NULL AND p.litm IS NULL)
                )
         ORDER BY
                mpf   NULLS LAST,
                an8   DESC,
                prodf NULLS LAST,
                prodm NULLS LAST,
                litm  NULLS LAST
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE PYRAMID_TABLE (mcu, mpf, an8, prodf, prodm, litm, val) AS
  SELECT '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL001', 'VAL002', 'TEST-MR-001', 'Value001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL001', 'VAL002', NULL,          'Value002' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL001', NULL,     NULL,          'Value003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '112', '431', 9999, NULL,     NULL,     NULL,          'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '112', '431',    0, NULL,     NULL,     NULL,          'Value005' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '112', NULL,     0, NULL,     NULL,     NULL,          'Value006' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION_TABLE (doco, mcu, mpf, an8, prodf, prodm, litm, Fetch_result) AS
  SELECT 10001, '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL001', 'VAL002', 'TEST-MR-001', 'Value001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10002, '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL001', 'VAL003', 'TEST-MR-098', 'Value003' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10003, '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL014', 'VAL055', 'TEST-MR-005', 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10004, '112', '431', 9999, 'VAL012', 'VAL050', 'TEST-MR-023', 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10005, '112', '345', 1293, 'STK001', 'STK067', 'TEST-MR-004', 'Value006' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DOCO
MCU
MPF
AN8
PRODF
PRODM
LITM
FETCH_RESULT
VAL




10001
112
431
9999
VAL001
VAL002
TEST-MR-001
Value001
Value001


10002
112
431
9999
VAL001
VAL003
TEST-MR-098
Value003
Value003


10003
112
431
9999
VAL014
VAL055
TEST-MR-005
Value004
Value004


10004
112
431
9999
VAL012
VAL050
TEST-MR-023
Value004
Value004


10005
112
345
1293
STK001
STK067
TEST-MR-004
Value006
Value006



fiddle

One option is to cross join tables, count max matching columns per TRANSACTION_TABLE.DOCO and per PYRAMID_TABLE.VAL and filter the result to those having the same number of max matchings OR one or both are zero to fetch the rows without matchings - in that case VAL is Null but if you want it anyway just select VAL instead of case expression in the code):
WITH      -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    PYRAMID_TABLE AS
        ( SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL002' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-001' LITM, 'Value001' VAL FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL002' PRODM, Null LITM, 'Value002' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, Null PRODM, Null LITM, 'Value003' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, Null PRODF, Null PRODM, Null LITM, 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 0 AN8, Null PRODF, Null PRODM, Null LITM, 'Value005' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '112' MCU, Null MPF, 0 AN8, Null PRODF, Null PRODM, Null LITM, 'Value006' FROM DUAL
        ),
    TRANSACTION_TABLE AS 
        ( SELECT 10001 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL002' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-001' LITM, 'Value001' FETCH_RESULT FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 10002 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL001' PRODF, 'VAL003' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-098' LITM, 'Value003' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 10003 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL014' PRODF, 'VAL055' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-005' LITM, 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 10004 DOCO, '112' MCU, '431' MPF, 9999 AN8, 'VAL012' PRODF, 'VAL050' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-023' LITM, 'Value004' FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 10005 DOCO, '112' MCU, '345' MPF, 1293 AN8, 'STK001' PRODF, 'STK067' PRODM, 'TEST-MR-004' LITM, 'Value006' FROM DUAL
        )

--    S Q L :
Select  DOCO, MCU, MPF, AN8, PRODF, PRODM, LITM, FETCH_RESULT, 
        Case When MAX_CNT_T + MAX_CNT_P <= 1 Then Null Else VAL End  "VAL"  -- or VAL if you want it anyway
From    ( Select    Max(Case When Nvl(p.LITM, '*') = t.LITM Then 1 Else 0 End  +
                    Case When Nvl(p.PRODM, '*') = t.PRODM Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.PRODF, '*') = t.PRODF Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.AN8, -99999) = t.AN8 Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.MPF, '*') = t.MPF Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.MCU, '*') = t.MCU Then 1 Else 0 End) Over(Partition By t.DOCO) "MAX_CNT_T", 
                    --
                    Max(Case When Nvl(p.LITM, '*') = t.LITM Then 1 Else 0 End  +
                    Case When Nvl(p.PRODM, '*') = t.PRODM Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.PRODF, '*') = t.PRODF Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.AN8, -99999) = t.AN8 Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.MPF, '*') = t.MPF Then 1 Else 0 End +
                    Case When Nvl(p.MCU, '*') = t.MCU Then 1 Else 0 End) Over(Partition By p.VAL) "MAX_CNT_P",
                    --
                    t.*, p.VAL
          From      TRANSACTION_TABLE t
          Cross Join PYRAMID_TABLE p
        )
Where     MAX_CNT_T = MAX_CNT_P OR MAX_CNT_T + MAX_CNT_P <= 1
Order By  DOCO 

/*      R e s u l t :
      DOCO MCU MPF        AN8 PRODF  PRODM  LITM        FETCH_RESULT VAL    
---------- --- --- ---------- ------ ------ ----------- ------------ --------------
     10001 112 431       9999 VAL001 VAL002 TEST-MR-001 Value001     Value001
     10002 112 431       9999 VAL001 VAL003 TEST-MR-098 Value003     Value003
     10003 112 431       9999 VAL014 VAL055 TEST-MR-005 Value004     Value004
     10004 112 431       9999 VAL012 VAL050 TEST-MR-023 Value004     Value004
     10005 112 345       1293 STK001 STK067 TEST-MR-004 Value006     Value006       */

